# '[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)' error for gmail.readonly, gmail.modify etc. scopes

Tags: python-3.x, google-oauth, gmail-api, django-allauth, imaplib

I am getting the error mentioned in the title for `gmail.readonly`, `gmail.modify` and all other scopes except for full account access scope (https://mail.google.com/). Here is what I am trying to do.

I have a `django-allauth` setup to get offline access tokens (OAUTH2 bearer token and refresh tokens). I am using this token to fetch emails using python's imaplib. It works when I specify full account access scope but doesn't work for `gmail.readonly` scope. And I don't need the full access as I just want to fetch the emails using `imaplib`.

[Reference Link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes)

Comment: Is this issue happening everytime with the readonly.scope? or was it happened one time? Because I tried in oauth play ground and all the scopes are working with Gmail API. Here is the link https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: Yes, it is happening every time. I think, if I request scope using gmail API and access the email using IMAP, the scope doesn't really apply, unless it's full access. This might be because the readonly scope will conflict with IMAP standard i.e. write access to mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved ! For me it was just that google waiting for the confirmation on my phone that it's really me who try to connect to my account